# detecting hrd drives on server without raid controller

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have a basic question. I have a server with 4 separate disk installed with ubuntu OS. The server does not seem to have  raid controller. Is there a way to work with all the 4 disks, that is mount all the 4 drives? Or do i have to work with only 1 drive where the OS is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic question imaginable...

You can

1. partition the disks and mount partitions from several disks (obviously)
2. make disks or partitions LVM PVs and create one LVM VG over several disks and create many small LVM LVs or one that (transparently) spans several disks
3. make disks or partitions mdraid volumes and either create redundancy (mirroring, RAID-1) or a big virtual volume (linear) or a faster big volume (striping, RAID-0) or both (RAID-5)